# Users roaming profiles not applying across PCs with folder redirect set Via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, folder-redirection

I inherited an 2008 AD server with no documentation that seems to be set up correctly and has been working fine for the most part. APPDATA and documents are redirected to server network shares over the LAN. However 1 by 1 more users kept having issues retrieving settings. Turns out when they change PC, almost none of they're settings follow them(especially outlooK).

The files are still accessible via the network and sometimes the user can only access a temporary profile when logging in.

Desktop nor Start menu was setup for redirect either.

Could it be users lack the security permissions(they're locked down pretty tight) or an issue with folder redirects.

***EDIT: I think it's because outlook and some other apps look for profiles and settings in the local folder not appdata so when a user loads on a new PC, these pre-installed apps find nothing relvant to that user.***

Comment: It depends.  How big are the roaming profiles? And what is the size of your network backbone?

Comment: 1. Roaming Profiles and Folder Redirection are two different things, are you using both? 2. Run GPRESULTS against an affected user and computer and make sure the correct GPO's are being applied and to check for errors. 3. Check the Group Policy event log on an affected machine and look for events that may be related to the problem.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure but the folder is redirected. 2. The RPC server is unavailable: It's big problem since whenever I try to enable it, it disconnects all users immediately. 3. Checking right now.

Comment: roaming profiles are pretty small on average: a few mb at most.  All users connected to a 10/100mb switch(about 15+ in this office).

Comment: I checked the reports on policies being applied: standard policies related to redirects....nothing unusual far as I can tell.

Comment: I strongly advise against folder redirection of the APPDATA folder. Better to use a roaming profile. Problem is, when the network is slow or unavailable, with roaming profiles you at least have a copy of your profile on the computer. With redirection it gets really frustrating very fast.

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned the PC's have been replaced, has the version of windows changed?

If so.. the roaming profiles will not be updated with the old settings and will either need to be copied (if supported) or manually re-entered.